# Is it possible to infer the name of a type on a null check

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I'm playing around with an webapi2 project.
Using a controller class ->

calling a service class, which handles business logic,  ->

which uses a repository that handles the database calls.
For readability I decided to have nullchecks in my service class (i.e.:

```
var object = _repository.GetById(5) ?? throw new CustomException(CustomException.Object1NotFound_Exception_Message);
```

).

This way my controller logic remains clean and readable, avoiding these checks in the controller methods [get/post/put/delete].

This way, I can try/catch my controller logic, and catch (customexception ex)
and call the extention method ex.converttostatuscoderesult. (as shown bellow).

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public const string Object1NotFound_Exception_Message = "Object not found using ID.";
    public const string Object2NotFound_Exception_Message = "Object2 not found using ID.";
    public const string UserNotAllowedX_Exception_Message = "Current user not allowed to do X.";
    public const string UserNotAllowedY_Exception_Message = "Current user not allowed to do Y.";
    <~even more strings containing ExceptionMessages> 

    public int ExceptionStatusCodeDefinition { get; set; }

    public CustomException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case Object1NotFound_Exception_Message:
            case Object2NotFound_Exception_Message:

                ExceptionStatusCodeDefinition = 404;
                break;
            case UserNotAllowedX_Exception_Message:
            case UserNotAllowedY_Exception_Message:
            case UserNotAllowedZ_Exception_Message:
                ExceptionStatusCodeDefinition = 403;
                break;
            default:
                ExceptionStatusCodeDefinition = 400;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static class CustomExceptionExtention
{
    public static IActionResult ConvertToStatusCodeResult(this CustomException exception)
    {
        return new Microsoft.AspNetCore.MvcStatusCodeResult(exception.ExceptionStatusCodeDefinition);
    }
}
```

This method however, requires that I setup the exception messages beforehand.
Which inevitably means i have a way too long list with exception messages.

I tried to refactor this trying to infer the name of the type and having a single exception message NotFound_Exception_Message. And appending the type name at runtime.

At first i tried a switch on Type, which does not work because of compiler reasons (the way i understand it, that if inheritance plays part, its impossible for the compiler to tell which typename i require)

Trying to circumvent this i made this class:

```
 public class TypeCase
{

 public static TypeCase GetType(Type type)
    {
        return new TypeCase(type);
    }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public TypeCase(object type)
    {
        TypeName = type.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as the object has a value, since its impossible to reflect upon an instance of an object if that object reference is null.

I've been breaking my head over this problem.
I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this problem, or explain to me why this is a bad solution.
Because I'm starting to think this approach is a definite code-smell.

(I'm aware that this approach does not return the exception message in the IActionResult. This is an issue too but beyond the scope of this question.)

I would very much appreciate help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer is no, you cannot do what you are trying to do. If you're throwing an exception because a function returned null, you cannot inspect the type of the object that would have been returned.

All you know is the *declared* type that `GetById` returns. In other words, if that function is declared as

```
Foo GetById(int id)
```

then you know that what it returns is a `Foo`. If you got a result back you could inspect it to see if its type is `Foo` or something else that inherits from `Foo`. But if you don't get a result, all you can know is that it would have been a `Foo`. But since you were asking for a `Foo`, that's the only type that matters.

In other words, there's no need to infer the type that the method returns. It declares the type that it returns. You know what the type is because you're calling the method to get an object of that type. If you didn't already know what the type was you wouldn't have a reason to call the method.

Since you know the type, and the only detail that varies one exception message from the next is the type, the next step is to figure out how to communicate the type in the exception message.

To be honest, this is the sort of thing we often overthink. You might be okay with this:

```
var object = _repository.GetById(5) ?? throw new CustomException("Foo not found using ID.");
```

Really, how bad is it? Even if the message was just "Foo not found," the stacktrace will show you the method, and from there you can determine that it's trying to retrieve it using an ID.

It's good to use constants, but it's much more important when the values have some significant meaning. If your next exception had a typo - "Blag not foound using ID" - it would be messy, but it wouldn't break anything. I could also see using a constant if the message was much longer and repeated.

That's my first recommendation by far. If you really want to ensure that your exception message is constant, declared only in one place, and you're creating custom exceptions anyway, you could do something like this (although I really, really wouldn't.)

```
// Really, don't do this.
public class ItemNotFoundByIdException<T> : Exception
{
    public ItemNotFoundByIdException()
    :base($"{typeof(T).Name} not found by ID.") { }
}
```

Then if you're trying to get a `Foo` by ID, you could do this:

```
var foo = _repository.GetById(5) ?? throw new ItemNotFoundByIdException<Foo>();
```

But this leads to a complicated hierarchy of exceptions. Unless you or someone else are going to catch this specific exception type and handle it differently from other exception types, it's just extra complexity with no benefit.

I know how we tend to obsess about this sort of thing, but it's not the important part of your application. It's not worth it. I would just hard-code these short exception messages where you need them.

Comment: I'm re-reading this answer again, and I felt like I had to thank you for this in-depth explanation. So even though this is quite late, thank you for taking the time to write down the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use generics, and create an helper function to made the check for you.

```
public static T GetWithNullCheck<T>(Func<T> fetchFunc)
{
    T t = fetchFunc();

    if (t != null) return t;

    var typeOfT = typeof(T);
    var typeName = typeOfT.Name;

    throw new CustomException($"{typeName} not found.");

    // short version
    // return fetchFunc() ?? throw new CustomException($"{typeof(T).Name} not found.");
}
```

And you could use it like this

```
var object = GetWithNullCheck(() => _repository.GetById(5));
```

Comment: How does this help with status codes for a ballooning list of possible exceptions?

Comment: The question is _"Is it possible to infer the name of a type on a null check?"_

Comment: The title says that, but the real problem is deeper than that.